# Pentaho Data Integration REST Client error handling

Tags: json, pentaho, rest-client, spoon, pdi

I'm passing around 300 POST requests to the REST Client using JSON.
But, my database shows only 285 results.

I want to identify the 5 rejected JSON requests.

Is there any step similar to error handling in REST Client in PDI.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a new step, e.g. a dummy and create a new hop from the REST Client step to the new one. You should see a selector box. Select "Error handling of step" in that box. The line to the new step should now be dotted red instead of solid black. You can now preview the new step and see your error lines.

Comment: you can try reading this blog : https://anotherreeshu.wordpress.com/2014/11/27/handling-error-in-pentaho-data-integration/ (Error Handling in PDI)

Comment: I have already tried this, i'm pointing the error handling to another table.But it is not storing any details.Is there any way to get to store the response for my JSON request.I need to figure out which JSON request is failing.

Comment: The error handling stream will not contain all "error" rows. It will only contain the rows which could not be sent to the target host because of an error in the REST Client step (e.g. malformed url, host not found). If you want to evaluate the HTTP response code you have to define a new field in the output fields section of the REST client step (HTTP status code field name).

Comment: Also you should check the step metrics of your transformation after you executed it. It shows an overview of each steps processing details. You should look for the first step in your stream where the Ouput column is smaller than the Input column. That's probably the point where your rows get lost.